# WSO2 Unexpected EOF in prolog

Tags: http, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a proxy that calls another local proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.6.0.
Basically, the definition is:

```
<proxy name="Proxy1" >
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <xslt/>
            <header name="Action" value="issueActivity" />
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/Proxy2" format="soap11"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <filter xpath="not(get-property('FAULT'))">
                <xslt/>
            </filter>
            <send />
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>

<proxy name="Proxy2">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <xslt />
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="Inbound" />
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <filter xpath="get-property('FAULT')">
                <then>
                    <sequence key="DefaultErrorSequence" />
                    <header name="To" action="remove" />
                </then>
                <else>
                    <property name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/> 
                    <xslt/>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <send />
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

In almost all calls, the flows works perfectly but, periodically, this error appears in the log when `Proxy1` try to call `Proxy2`:

```
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:03:35,431]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  Receiving response while the handler is in an inconsistent state REQUEST_HEAD
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:03:35,432] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    [...]
```

At the end of the error in the log:

```
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:04:35,435]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE 
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:04:35,436]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_CODE : 101507
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:04:35,436]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : Error in Sender
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:04:35,437]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_DETAIL : Error in Sender 
TID: [0]  [ESB]  TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-05-08 12:04:35,437]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : null
```

According the WSO2 documentation, the error `101507` means `Connection canceled`.

The question is what the cause of this error? It's a problem with client or server?

**UPDATE**

Aparently, the cause of the error is the same described in this question: [WSO2 ESB unknown error code 102511](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183687/wso2-esb-unknown-error-code-102511)

Comment: Does it happen for every invocation of proxy1 or it happens time to time?

Comment: @RezaAmeri Time to time. About 5% of the requests.

Comment: When error occurs, what is the message is passing through the system? it is , xml/text/html/json?

Comment: And as a correction, in your second proxy define the fault sequence..DO not use filter mediator to identify faults. And when error occurs do you get response from your inbound endpoint? That is at your second proxy's out sequence use the log mediator with full level and see , it prints the response. This is how you need to isolate the issue.

Comment: @Ratha, it's XML. And thanks for the advice. When this error occurs, the client doesn't receives anything, it just waits for response. The Inbound endpoint is not called in this case.

Comment: So, in this case what is your message flow? proxy1-->proxy2(insequence) no endpoint call? So, does proxy2 receive the request? i mean at insequence, keep a log mediator and see, whether it receives the request or not?

Comment: The proxy2 doesn't receives the request. The error is when the proxy1 try to call proxy2. A log right before the `send` of the proxy1 prints correctly, but a log at the beginning of `inSequence` of the proxy2 doesn't.

Comment: @Elias Can you try to change proxy2 to a collection of sequences, in this way we can find out that does "send" mediator have problem or the error is some where else.

Comment: I mean you just change the insequence and outsequence of proxy2 to new sequences and just call them in proxy1 instead of sending to proxy2 endpoint can invoking it.

Comment: @RezaAmeri changing to sequences, aparently the error is gone. However the architecture of the services I'm developing requires the previous model (proxy1 -> proxy2).

Comment: Don't you think it might be a bug in the passthrough transport?

Comment: @Elias I do't think so! Try proxy1 -> proxy2 architechture with setting receiving sequence for send mediator in proxy1 and forget it's built in out sequence. I think problem is here.

Comment: @RezaAmeri the proplem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Have you make Return Request Status checkbox enable at operation section while writing query? This may cause the problem..Try it..

Comment: This proxy doesn't involve the Data Services Server, just the ESB. But there's others that involve. Do you say that this checkbox should be unmarked?

Comment: Thanks for answer @user3129056. I think it's nothing to do with the request status. My guess is that's a bug in the Passthrough Transport.

Comment: @user3129056 I wonder how data service definition can affect mentioned problem, would you please explain it more?

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the all comments so far, I think first achievement was that the problem was solved when instead of `Proxy1->Proxy2` architecture, changing the `Proxy2` to sequences and call them with Sequence mediator instead of invoking them with send mediator removes the errors previously has been shown.
That worked properly but since we need to have the `Proxy1->Proxy2` architecture, I think defining the "outSequence" of `Proxy1` as receiving sequence in "inSequence" of `Proxy1` and sending it to `Proxy2` using Send mediator with `Proxy2` endpoint would be the solution.