# Sending large payloads via WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, large-files, wso2-esb

I'm trying to do some load testing on the WSO2 ESB, and I have a SOAP message with a large payload that I'd like to send (10+MB, sometimes reaching 50 inbound, and sometimes even 300 outbound).

I'm using curl to send the messages, first to the backend SOPAUI service. This goes through fine. However when I send the message via a proxy service on the ESB, curl fails to finish uploading the file, and gets slower and slower as the upload progresses. The logs from the ESB do not seem to be reporting anything useful.

I have set the timeout on this to 20 minutes, and it still does not complete. Turning on MTOM has no effect, and I am using a simple passthrough proxy. The proxy service functions fine with small message sizes.

What else can I look into to get this working? If it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had to switch to using the NHTTP transport rather than the Passthrough transport, thanks to this question here for prompting looking into this: [WSO2 ESB unknown error code 102511](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183687/wso2-esb-unknown-error-code-102511)

Requires an edit in carbon.xml, detailed in the accepted answer from the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to configure Message Relay

in repository/conf/axis2.xml, you configure :

- org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder as the messageBuilder's class associated with your contentType (text/xml for exemple if soap11 of application/soap+xml with soap12)
- org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter as the messageFormatter's class

Have a look there : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Message+Relay